# The Validity Of "Else-IF" in Unity (Or any C# for that matter)

Tags: c#, unity

While I'm speaking specifically for my use in Unity, I'm sure this question probably applies to C# in general. I've seen a lot of debate on the use of the "else if" statement. Particularly, I'm testing for input in my update. Is it more efficient to have

if (input blah blah)

If (input other blah)

if (input more blah)

OR

if (input blah)

else if (input more blah)

else if (input other blah)

Personally, I don't really understand the difference between if and else if though I've read about it many different times and in different languages. So I'm asking just from your personal experiences and not what you've read on the internet. Do you have a preference? Does it even matter?

Update: Thanks for the answers. Actually does make more sense now. I don't know why I wasn't seeing it that way. Sorry for the off topic thing. (Can't upvote as of now because reputation)

Comment: the first case `up to 3` of those "input blahs" can run. the second case means that `1 of those 3` "input blahs" will run `at most`

Comment: Use the tool best made for the job. If else if, is most appropriate, then use that. If 'if' is the best, then use that. You should write code for humans first, before rewriting the code for the machines.

As far as the difference: if X, then Y, else Z. If X is true, only Y is done, otherwise Z is done. With simply an: if X then Y; if Z then W, then if X is true, then Y is done, AND if Z is true then W is done. There is an exclusivity with the former way, and the latter can run as many times as X or Z are true. Again, use the one that is the best for readability and what logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand `else if`, consider the following **code A**:

```
if (condition_1)
{
    DoA();
}
else if (condition_2)
{
    DoB();
}
```

The above code is exactly the same as **code B**

```
if (condition_1)
{
    DoA();
}
else
{
    if (condition_2)
    {
        DoB();
    }
}
```

Compare this to **code C**:

```
if (condition_1)
{
    DoA();
}
if (condition_2)
{
    DoB();
}
```

In code A and B, if `condition_1` is true, `DoB()` will never run, regardless of whether `condition_2` is true or not. In code C, `condition_2` will be evaluated regardless of whether `condition_1` is true or not.

General programming questions are more suited for Stack Overflow though...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what debate you are speaking of, but else if is a required construct in most programming languages, including C#. How else do I express the following?

```
if ( i == 0 )
{
   DoPrimaryAction();
}
else if ( i < 2 )
{
   DoSecondaryAction();
}
else if ( i < 4 )
{
   DoTertiaryAction();
}
```

if it were rewritten as

```
if ( i == 0 )
{
   DoPrimaryAction();
}
if ( i < 2 )
{
   DoSecondaryAction();
}
if ( i < 4 )
{
   DoTertiaryAction();
}
```

Then PrimaryAction(), SecondaryAction() and TertiaryAction() would be called whenever i is zero.

You might rewrite it as a function:

```
void Action::DoAction( int i )
{
    if ( i == 0 )
    {
       DoPrimaryAction();
       return;
    }
    if ( i < 2 )
    {
        DoSecondaryAction();
        return;
    }
    if ( i < 4 )
    {
        DoTertiaryAction();
        return;
    }
}
```

Where each if case returns to prevent the following case from being called. While this is done often it is cumbersome to require it.

You could use switch statements, but those don't work if unrelated conditional cases.

Can you cite what debate you are talking about?